# Clear contents of half of a matrix diagonally across

Tags: vba, excel, matrix

I want to clear the contents of a matrix diagonally across going diagonally across and down the rows to the last row in the matrix.

But I cannot seem to get the macro to clear contents to the last row in each column as I move the cell reference down and across diagonally

Help appreciated.

```
Sub Tidy_Matrix()
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws5 As Worksheet
Dim Lastrow As Long

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws5 = wb.Sheets(5)

Lastrow = ws5.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
'column
For i = 2 To Lastrow
'row
j = i - 1 To Lastrow
    ws5.Cells(j, i).ClearContents
Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need two loops for this you can do it with just one

```
Sub Tidy_Matrix()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws5 As Worksheet

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws5 = wb.Sheets(5)

    With ws5
        For i = 2 To .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
            With .Cells(i, 1)
                Range(.Offset(0, 0), .Offset(0, j)).ClearContents
                j = j + 1
            End With
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to add one iteration of inner loop:

```
For i = 2 To Lastrow
    j = (i - 1) To (Lastrow + 1)
        ws5.Cells(j, i).ClearContents
    Next j
Next i
```

Comment: Needs to clear contents of the column though across diagaonally - as in half of the matrix as mentioned above.

Comment: So as it moves across diagaonally i want it to clear the cells to last row as it sweeps across the columns

Comment: j = i - 1 To Lastrow + 1 gets marked in red by my excel VBA Its not valid code I dont think

Comment: Try wrapping it in brackets, as I did.

Answer (score 0):

if you would like to delete the diagonal terms and all the terms below, it should be

```
Sub Tidy_Matrix()
Dim Lastrow As Long

Lastrow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row


Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long

For i = 1 To Lastrow
For j = i To Lastrow
Cells(j, i).ClearContents
Next j
Next i

End Sub
```